# Allow CognitoUser to use AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

### My problem:

Using AWS SDK to invoke an AWS Lambda is giving me config errors

```
CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config
```

### What I found:

Loggin in a user for the first time initiates proper config settings, but it's lost upon page refresh.

### The Goal:

Use...the code below, even after the user has refreshed the page

```
 lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        // console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      } // successful response
    });
```

### Below is how I signIn a user from a cognitoUserPool the 1st time

### Step 1 capture username and password

```
trySignIn(username, password) {
        console.log("trying to sign in");
        var authenticationData = {
          Username: username,
          Password: password
        };
```

### Step 2 use new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails

```
        var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(
          authenticationData
        );
```

### Step 3 configure UserPool with UserData

```
        var poolData = {
          UserPoolId: "myPoolId", // Your user pool id here
          ClientId: "myPoolClient" // Your client id here
        };

        var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

        var userData = {
          Username: username,
          Pool: userPool
        };
```

#### Step 4 Get a CognitoUser object

```
        var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
          onSuccess: function(result) {
            var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();

            console.log(result);

            //POTENTIAL: Region needs to be set if not already set previously elsewhere.
            //AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";  //moved to component did mount

            AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
              IdentityPoolId: "myidentiy-id-pool-id", // your identity pool id here
              Logins: {
                // Change the key below according to the specific region your user pool is in.
                "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1": result
                  .getIdToken()
                  .getJwtToken()
              }
            });
```

### Step 5 Here we can configure the AWS SDK to use things like AWS.Lambda / AWS.S3

```
            //refreshes credentials using AWS.CognitoIdentity.getCredentialsForIdentity()
            AWS.config.credentials.refresh(error => {
              if (error) {
                console.error(error);
              } else {
                // Instantiate aws sdk service objects now that the credentials have been updated.
                // example: var s3 = new AWS.S3();
                console.log("Successfully logged!");
              }
            });
```

### Problem is event after saving the UserObject to storage I lose the AWS.config information and I can't reconfigure it without asking for the users password everytime

```
            var user = { username: username };
            localStorage.setItem("cognitoUser", JSON.stringify(user));
            console.log(cognitoUser);
            console.log(user);
```

### The Question ?

How can I configure AWS.config having only access to the cognitoUser Object from storage, but not the user password

## Update: <-- Did Not Work

I'm thinking it might be possible to save the variable created in Step 5 to storage.

```
var lambdaTry = new AWS.Lambda 

localStorage.setItem("lambdaTry", JSON.stringify(lambdaTry));
```